# Retrofit2 post array to match php array param

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a problem with sending array params to a php server.

The server developer suggests that the server log should look like this when I send a array.

```
'thumbnails' => 
 array (
  0 => 
 array (
  'seq' => '1',
  'playtime' => '1',
  'url' => 'url1',
),
1 => 
array (
  'seq' => '2',
  'playtime' => '4',
  'url' => 'url2',
),
2 => 
array (
  'seq' => '3',
  'playtime' => '7',
  'url' => 'url3',
),
3 => 
array (
  'seq' => '4',
  'playtime' => '10',
  'url' => 'url4',
    ),
  ),
)
```

I've tried many methods on google, but the server doesn't seem to get what it needs.

The below is what I've tried.

** Class Thumbnail contains field seq, playtime, url. It is Serializable.

(1)

```
//Server doesn't throw an error, but fails to read the thumbnail data.
@Field("thumbnails[]") Thumbnail[] thumbnails
```

(2)

```
//Server doesn't throw an error, but fails to read the thumbnail data.
@Field("thumbnails[]") String[] thumbnails
```

(3)

```
//Server doesn't throw an error, but fails to read the thumbnail data.
@Field("thumbnails[]") ArrayList<Thumbnail> thumbnails
```

(4)

```
//Server throws an error.
@Field("thumbnails") ArrayList<Thumbnail> thumbnails
```

(5)

```
//Server throws an error.
@Field("thumbnails") String thumbnails
```

What else can I try? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `HashMap`:

```
@FieldMap HashMap<Integer, Thumbnail> data
```

You can populate the HashMap as follows:

```
Thumbnail firstThumbnail = new Thumbnail(...);
Thumbnail secondThumbnail = new Thumbnail(...);
HashMap<Integer, Thumbnail> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put(0, firstThumbnail);
map.put(1, secondThumbnail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can send through raw format using retrofit2 easily just create a model class

> @SerializedName("product")
>      @Expose
>      List oneProductModels;

```
public CartPost(String user_id, List<OneProductModel> oneProductModels) {
this.user_id = user_id;
this.oneProductModels = oneProductModels;
}

@POST("/api/r_etiket")
Call<Result> post_etiket(@Body modelClass);
```

and call your API from Activity/fragment like this

> 

```
 ApiUtil.getServiceClass().selfpickup(new CODPost(cartResults))
                    .enqueue(new Callback<SelfPickupResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<SelfPickupResponse> call, Response<SelfPickupResponse> response) {
    }

     @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<SelfPickupResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    rotateLoading.stop();
                    Log.d("codERROR", "onFailure: "+t);

                }
            });
```